# Map projection for the surface $z=xy$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

(Hope I used the right tag; please correct if not.)

Clarification:

In the title, I mean "map projection" in the geographical sense of projecting the surface of a sphere onto a plane, but instead of a sphere, we project from $z=xy$.

Background:

Let $x=a/b$, $y=b/c$, and $z=a/c$. I'm interested in creating a flat 2D map of this surface in such a way that $x$, $y$, and $z$  are somewhat like three cardinal directions, with $a$,$b$,$c$ between them.

Question:

How to map the surface $z=xy$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ in such a way that the lines $x=k$, $y=k$ and $z=k$ curve little?

Simply projecting onto the $x,y$ plane is trivial but that puts all the curvature into the $z=k$ lines. I need a non-linear transformation of that map so that the other two lines share the "curving burden", if you know what I mean.

Comment: what is cardinal direction?

Comment: @janmarqz [North/West/South/East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction), but I just meant it as a geographical analogy. I want three directions on the map to point approximately along those lines, without too much sensitivity to where we are on the map.